# Unable to scrape drop down menu using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape the product pages on Breitling's website for various pieces of information.

Example page: https://www.breitling.com/gb-en/watches/navitimer/b01-chronograph-46/AB0127211C1A1/

I am having trouble scraping the watch's strap material given in the dropdown menu above the "ADD TO BAG" button ('steel 1.4435' in the example's case).

The specific element I want is:

```
<small class="dd-selected-description dd-desc dd-selected-description-truncated">Steel 1.4435</small>
```

However, this is not returned in the response to my GET request. The closest element to the `<small>` tag is a `<div>` element with `id='strap-selector-list'`.

However, when calling `soup.find(id='strap-selector-list')` it shows the `<div>` as containing nothing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.breitling.com/gb-en/watches/navitimer/b01-chronograph-46/AB0127211C1A1/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

soup.find(id='strap-selector-list')
```

returns

```
<div id="strap-selector-list"></div>
```

How can I get there to be information inside (as is shown when you open the inspector?)

[Screenshot of page with inspector open highlighting areas of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma2pm.jpg)

What I've tried:

1. Spoofing headers. I copy/pasted all the request headers (apart from cookies) in the Network tab in developer tools. I used them in the GET request (only including changed lines for brevity)

```
headers = {'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'dnt': '1',
'referer': 'https://www.breitling.com/gb-en/watches/navitimer/?search%5Bref%5D=&search%5Bsorting%5D=newest',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate, same-origin, cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

2. Checked XHR requests. There are only 3 when the page loads. One is for the checkout basket's status, one gives info on retailers such as their store locations and the other is status.php which gives a 404 error.

   If you click the drop-down menu, no XHR requests are sent.

   If you click on any of the items in the drop-down menu, you are taken to the product page for that item.
3. Using different parsers e.g. html.parser makes no difference
4. Adding in cookies to the headers and performing a normal GET request, also no difference
5. First creating `session = requests.Session()` and doing `r = session.get(url)` with and without `headers=headers` also doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are looking for resides under a `script` element.

All you need to do is to load the JSON that is returned as the script body and traverse the dict.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pprint

url = 'https://www.breitling.com/gb-en/watches/navitimer/b01-chronograph-46/AB0127211C1A1/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')

script = soup.find(id='app-reference-versions')
pprint.pprint(json.loads(script.contents[0]))
```

output

https://pastebin.com/kGhMQt61

Comment: @DarkLeader I was scanning the page source code looking for words  like "1.4435"

Comment: yeah i found the location of the drop menu in the html but like the OP i couldn't get the content and i didn't find any id tags

Comment: @DarkLeader Do "view source" and look for `script type="application/json"`

Comment: how do you view the source?

Comment: @DarkLeader Yes do control + F and type in `type="application/json"` or `app-reference-versions`. You'll see the `script` element then