# Python: how to monitor availability ecommerce products for all sub products selectable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, python-requests-html

I wanna to **scrape** the following product https://www.decathlon.it/p/disco-ghisa-bodybuilding-28mm/_/R-p-7278?mc=1042303&c=NERO

But for the product we could select different weight (from 0.5 to 20kg). I have created the following code, but It give me only the first weight (0,5kg) and not the other one.

```
import requests
import re
import time

urls = ['p/disco-ghisa-bodybuilding-28mm/_/R-p-7278.html']
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

def main(site):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(site.format(url), headers=user_agent)
            match = re.search('availability.+org\/(.*?)"', r.text)
            print("url: {:<70}, status: {}".format(r.url, match.group(1)))

while True:
    main("https://www.decathlon.it/{}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

But I wanna to figure out the following output

```
weight 0,5kg outofstock, 1kg outofstock and so on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably check BeautifulSoup python library and discussion from this link [Unable to scrape drop down menu using BeautifulSoup and Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292504/unable-to-scrape-drop-down-menu-using-beautifulsoup-and-requests) or use Selenium just to change option from dropdown menu what you can learn more about here https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html